# Same number of documents returned by Elasticsearch API

Tags: api, elasticsearch, elk

Good day!

There was a problem with the Elasticsearch API. I wrote a script in which I execute several different requests. In these queries, I try to calculate the number of documents in the last half hour from different hosts.

In all requests I use "GET /log/_count"

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
                "must": [
                {
                        "match": { "host": "xxx" }
                },
                {
                        "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                        "gte": "now-30m",
                                        "lte": "now"
                                }
                        }
                }
                ]
        }
}

"query": {
        "bool": {
                "must": [
                {
                        "match": { "host" : "yyy" }
                },
                {
                        "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                        "gte": "now-30m",
                                        "lte": "now"
                                }
                        }
                }
                ]
        }
}

"query": {
        "bool": {
                "must": [
                {
                        "match": { "host" : "zzz" }
                },
                {
                        "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                        "gte": "now-30m",
                                        "lte": "now"
                                }
                        }
                }
                ]
        }
}
```

And another request for verification:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
                "filter": {
                        "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                        "gte": "now-30m",
                                        "lte": "now"
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

But when I run the script, I get approximately the same number of documents. And even in the last request, which should show the sum of all the documents, the same amount is displayed, although it only has "range" configured.

> XXX: 15691

> YYY: 15689

> ZZZ: 15689

> ALL: 15689

Is this normal behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

UPD.

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
                "must": [
                {
                        "match_phrase": { "host" : "xxx" }
                },
                {
                        "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                        "gte": "now-30m",
                                        "lte": "now"
                                }
                        }
                }
                ]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be an expected behaviour.

Reason is that you have two queries which works on `now`. You might be executed query1 on time1 and  query2 on time. `now` is different for both time1 and time2.

In the mean time (time2 - time1), there could be some docs added. Hence you are seeing the little difference.

To get count for all the hosts,

```
GET logs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "hosts": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "xxx": {
            "match": {
              "host": "xxx"
            }
          },
          "yyy": {
            "match": {
              "host": "yyy"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "range": {
          "date_range": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "to": "now-30m"
              },
              {
                "from": "now"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If your values are more than one words, you need to use `match phrase` than `match`.

Comment: But the search parameters in each request are different. Shouldn't the number of documents differ regardless of the time interval?

These documents are sent from different hosts to the ELK stack, but I just count the number of documents from each host. In addition, "must" is used there as a logical "AND", so I should only get the number of documents from the host "xxx" in the last half hour, but this does not happen. I get the total number of documents.

Comment: Host xxx could be sending documents near real time. Isn't? And that is also corect. You have different query params. That could also cause the difference.

Comment: Documents are sent in real time.
If I execute a script with all four requests, I get plus or minus the same number of documents. That is, any of these queries returns the total number of all documents. That is, if I execute the script now, then I will get about 15000-16000 documents from all requests, but in theory I should get much fewer documents from the first three requests. And already if you add the returned values ​​of the first three queries, you should get what the fourth query returns.
Is there any way to get what I want? Or is it already features of Elasticsearch?

Comment: @vovagib check my edit and it ll give you host wise counts for last 30mins.

Comment: Good day!
Thanks for the help. I used your request, but I still get the same number of documents for all hosts. `xxx=2585, yyy=2585 and zzz=2585`. This is the total number of all documents in the last half hour. I need to get the number of documents from a single host in the last half hour

Comment: The problem is that I do not need ALL documents for the last half hour. Only documents from ONE host in the last half hour are needed.

Comment: I think I understood what the problem was. I used match instead of match_phrase. Now I tried to change "match" to "match_phrase" in your request and the number of documents for each host has become different. Let me know if I am wrong. And thank you for your help.

Comment: If my previous comment is correct, please correct your answer. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Can you show me a sample host name and mapping for the field host? That's where the different lies I belive.

Comment: I did not understand your question a bit. I updated my question by adding a code block with my request at the end. In this form, the request works as I need it. Now it shows the number of documents only for host xxx

Comment: I think you have some other host name in your actual data. Is it IP address? And what is the output of `http://host:port/indexName/_mapping`?

Comment: Good day!
I don’t have enough rights to work with _mapping. Therefore, I can not send you a conclusion. I can only say that now the script is working out as I need thanks to match_phrase. Many thanks for the help. Please correct your answer if you want me to mark it as correct